# what does "/index.php?admin/admin_dashboard" in my url mean

Tags: php, mysql

have an already coded application in `PHP/MySQL` about school management. I am trying to further customize it as it is no longer serviced by the provider. I see `/index.php?admin/admin_dashboard` on the address bar but cannot find any file named `admin_dashboard`. Can anybody help about what it means? I am a novice programmer in PHP with practically no experience.

actually, it is designed using bootstrap and I am unable to see any icons on the page

Comment: Can you tell what is the issue? Which framework you are using?

Comment: You will have to look at `index.php` and then find where it reads the query params to determine what it actually does with the stuff after the `?`. That's an interesting format though. Look for `$_GET`, `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, or `PHP_URL_QUERY` -- those are the ways of accessing that data AFAICT.

Comment: That's a get parameter. i don't see any key to access it in your php code..unless you are using any framework or rewrite url

Comment: codeigniter framework is used :define('ENVIRONMENT', isset($_SERVER['CI_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['CI_ENV'] : 'production')